# changing background color of togglebutton when checked

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, togglebutton

I am trying the distinguish the state of the toggle button when clicked. I have the snippet below

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="OnOffToggleImageStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Height="60" Content="Text" Style="{StaticResource OnOffToggleImageStyle}">
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However this does not work when IsChecked value is set to "True" in the style. When set to false it works.

I wonder why. Any answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running your code sample, it appears the style is conflicting with the 'chrome' of the `ToggleButton` (i.e. the original style of the button).

It would probably be better in this situation to override the template of the `ToggleButton` to behave in the manner you desire.  An ugly example can be found below:

```
<Style x:Key="myToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border x:Name="outer"
        BorderBrush="White"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Opacity=".9"
        Background="Transparent">
          <Border x:Name="inner"
          Margin="8"
          BorderThickness="0"
          Background="{
            Binding Background, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <Grid x:Name="container">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <TextBlock x:Name="display"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={
                RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              Foreground="White"
              FontSize="11"
              FontFamily="Segoe UI"
              FontStyle="Normal"
              FontWeight="Normal"
              Margin="8,0,0,4"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>
          </Border>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="outer" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter TargetName="outer" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: lbbster,can you advise where to find the code of original togglebutton's style? Thanks in advance

Comment: @nerielle Late answer but if somebody search that :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks this really helped. Now my question is, are there docs somewhere that show how the "chrome" looks like for each of these basic elements (ToggleButton, Button, etc.)?